# How to prove $\,{\rm order}(a^k) = n/\gcd(n,k)\,$ for $\,n={\rm order}(a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is an exercise from "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" I'm not sure how to solve.

> **Exercise:** Let $\langle a\rangle $ be a (cyclic) group of order $n$. Prove that the order of $a^k=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$.

**Direction:** (1) Let $d=\gcd(n,k)$, thus by the Euclidian algorithm we can find $X,Y\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $d=Xn+Yk$, thus, $a^d=a^{Xn+Yk}=a^{Xn}a^{Yk}=(a^n)^X(a^k)^Y=(a^k)^Y$. What to do from here?

(2) We know that $d|n$, thus $\langle a^{n/d} \rangle$ is of order $d$ and $\langle a^d \rangle$ is of order $\frac{n}{d}=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$. Is it mean that $d=k$? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have two things to show. Namely that:

1. $(a^k)^{n/\gcd(n,k)}=e$ (where $e$ denotes the identity)

and that $n/\gcd(n,k)$ is the smallest positive power $p$ of $a^k$ such that $(a^k)^p=e$:

2. For all $m>0$: $(a^k)^m=e \implies n/\gcd(n,k)\leq m$

The first part is easy:

$$
(a^k)^{n/\gcd(n,k)}=(a^n)^{k/\gcd(n,k)}=e^{k/\gcd(n,k)}=e
$$

For the second part, let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $(a^k)^m=a^{km}=e$. Since the order of $a$ is $n$, it follows that $n\mid km$. Therefore we also have

$$
\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}\mid \frac{k}{\gcd(n,k)}m
$$

Now $\gcd(n/\gcd(n,k),k/\gcd(n,k))=1$ (try to prove this), so it follows that

$$
n/\gcd(n,k)\mid m
$$

Hence in particular $n/\gcd(n,k)\leq m$.

Comment: What if $n=25$ and $k=30$? then $\gcd(n/\gcd(n,k),k)=5$.

Comment: @Silent Uncountable should have instead wrote $$ n\mid km \implies \frac{n}{g}\mid \frac{k}{g}m\implies \frac{n}{g}\mid m, $$ where $g=\gcd(n,k)$, since $\gcd(n/g,k/g)=1$ is true (while $\gcd(n/g,k)=1$ needn't be).

Comment: @anon good one!

Comment: Uncountable, [what is the relation between 'the order of $x^k = n/{\gcd(k,n)}$' and this corollary of Lagrange's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900950)?

Answer (score 16):

The order of $a^k$ is the smallest $r>0$ such that $a^{kr}=e$, i.e. such that $kr$ is a multiple of the order $n$ of $a$. This means $kr$ is the least common multiple of $k$ and $n$.

As $\operatorname{lcm}(k,n)=\dfrac{kn}{\gcd(k,n)}$, we have:
$\quad r=\dfrac{n}{\gcd(k,n)}.$

Comment: Bernard, [what is the relation between 'the order of $x^k = n/{\gcd(k,n)}$' and this corollary of Lagrange's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2900950)?

Comment: Do you mean corollary 2.8.10?  $x^k$ is a element of the group generated by $x$, which has order $n$. But this result is more precise than the corollary.

Comment: Bernard, interesting, but no. I really mean Cor 2.8.11 intending to use $\gcd(k,p)=1$ for any or all $0 < k < p$. Like somehow we might show that the orders of the non-identity elements are given by $p/\gcd(k,p)$, which of course simplifies to $p$.

Comment: It might be used. However, I wonder whether the notion of order of an element doesn't ultimately on Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Thanks Bernard!

Answer (score 2):

You can think additively in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Say $\bar a$ a generator of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$, whence $\gcd(a,n)=1$. The order of $k\bar a \in \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is by definition the least positive integer, say $o(k\bar a)$, such that $o(k\bar a)k\bar a=\bar 0$. But, $o(k\bar a)k\bar a=\overline{o(k\bar a)ka}$, and hence:

\begin{alignat}{1}
o(k\bar a)k\bar a=\bar 0 &\iff o(k\bar a)ka \equiv 0 \pmod n \\
&\iff o(k\bar a)ka=mn
\end{alignat}

for some $m\in \Bbb Z$. Therefore, the order of $k\bar a$ is the *least* positive *integer* of the form ($*$) $\frac{n}{(ka/m)}$, and it is then gotten when the denominator in ($*$) is the *greatest divisor of $ka$ which is also divisor of $n$*, namely:

\begin{alignat}{1}
o(k\bar a) &= \frac{n}{\gcd(ka,n)} \\
&= \frac{n}{\gcd(k,n)} \\
\end{alignat}
where the last equality follows from $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is simpler (and more $\rm\color{darkorange}{general}$) using basic gcd / lcm laws (vs. Bezout gcd identity).

**Lemma** $\ \ (a^{\large k})^{\large j}\! =  1\color{#90f}{\underset{a^n\,=\,1}\Longleftarrow}\!\!\!\!\!\color{#0a0}{\overset{{\rm ord}\,a\,=\,n}{\Longrightarrow}} n/(n,k)\mid j\,.\ \  $  **Proof**: $ $ immediate by [Euclids Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1883940/242), i.e.

$$ (a^{\large k})^{\large j}\! =  1\color{#90f}{\underset{a^n\,=\,1}\Longleftarrow}\!\!\!\!\!\color{#0a0}{\overset{{\rm ord}\,a\,=\,n}{\Longrightarrow}} n\mid kj\!\iff\! n\mid nj,kj\!\color{#c00}\iff\! n\mid(nj,kj)\!=\!(n,k)j\!\iff\! n/(n,k)\mid j\qquad$$

$\,\color{#0a0}{\rm First\ (\Rightarrow)}\,$ [is by](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,n = {\rm\ ord}\, a,\,$  $\rm\color{#c00}{third}$ by the [definition/universal property of the gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) and the [gcd distributive law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242)  $\,\color{#90f}{\rm Note}$ that the proof of direction  $\color{#90f}{(\Leftarrow)}$ needs only $\,\color{#90f}{a^n =1},\,$ not $\,\color{#0a0}{{\rm ord}\,a = n}$.

---

**Alternatively**, dually, we can use lcm instead of gcd, using notation $\,[x,y] :={\rm lcm}(x,y),$

$$ (a^{\large k})^{\large j}\! =  1\color{#90f}{\underset{a^n\,=\,1}\Longleftarrow}\!\!\!\!\!\color{#0a0}{\overset{{\rm ord}\,a\,=\,n}{\Longrightarrow}} n\mid kj\iff n,k\mid kj\iff [n,k]\mid kj\iff [n,k]/k\mid j\qquad\qquad$$

Both proofs are equivalent by $\ [n,k]/k = n/(n,k),\ $ i.e. $\ [n,k](n,k) = nk\ $ [[gcd $*$ lcm law]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318902/242)

---

**Corollary** $\ \ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{{\rm ord}(a) = n\,\Rightarrow\,{\rm ord}(a^{\large k}) = \dfrac{n}{(n,k)} = \dfrac{[n,k]}k}\ $ since, generally

$\qquad\qquad\quad\underbrace{ b^{\large j} = 1\iff i\mid j}_{\small \textstyle \text{Lemma has }\, b = a^k}\ $ [is equivalent to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242)  $\,b\,$ has order $\,i.\,$

---

$\rm\color{darkorange}{Generality\!\!:}$ proofs using gcd laws (vs. Bezout)  apply much more generally, e.g. in UFDs where Bezout fails, e.g.  $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y],\,$  e.g. $\,(x,2) = 1 = (x,y)\,$ but the gcds cannot be written as linear combinations, else $\, 1 = x\,f(x,y) + y\,g(x,y)\Rightarrow\,1=0\,$ by evaluating at $\,x=0=y.\,$