# If g is a primitive root modulo m and k | ( m-1),

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

If g is a primitive root modulo m and k | ( m-1), show  that g^((m-1)/k) has order k? What theorem do we need to use to prove this proposition.

Comment: If ord$_ma=d,$ ord$_m(a^k)=\dfrac d {(d,k)}$  (Proof  @Page$#95$ of http://archive.org/details/NumberTheory_862

Comment: Is $m$ a prime? Otherwise the group order is $\phi(m)$ instead of $m-1$. There are good reasons for automatically assuming $m$ to be prime, when discussing primitive roots, but should $m$ be a power of an odd prime, the group $\Bbb{Z}_m^*$ is still cyclic, and we can choose to call any generator of that group a primitive root modulo $m$. And in that case $g^k$ has order $\phi(m)/\gcd(\phi(m),k)$. If $m=p^a$, then $\phi(m)=(p-1)p^{a-1}$. All in accordance with the general result lab bhattacharjee cited (valid in any group actually).

Comment: @lab No need to refer offsite when there are plenty of proofs here, e.g. [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1906763/242)