# Basic order of element in number theory qestion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $ord_{341} 171 = t$. Show that for any positive integer
k, $ord_{341} (171^{k}) = t $ if and only if k is an odd integer that is not a multiple of 5.

This doesnt seem right useing the CRT it implies that $ord_{341} 171 $ we have that $ 171^{10} \equiv 1 \mod11 $ and $ 171^{30} \equiv 1 \mod31 $ which implys that $ 171^{30} \equiv 1 \mod341 $ which is clearly a multiple of 5... in fact i thought i found the least such interger was $10$ which is supposed to be the order no; what am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2303826/if-g-is-a-primitive-root-modulo-m-and-k-m-1

Comment: Yeah i read the theorem and it's proof that is pointed to in linked post and i still have no idea why the order isn't 10.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: It's part of a problem from a first course in number theory at my university it's not from an actual book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong: $\text{ord}_{341}(171)=10$.  Now you need to show that $\text{ord}_{341}(171^k)=10$ exactly when $k$ is an odd integer that is not a multiple of $5$.  One nice way to do that is suppose $k=10r+s$, with $r$ a positive integer, and $0 \le s <10$.  You can quickly show that you have but $10$ cases to consider.

Comment: Weird i was not understanding the question, is there a specific name for the set of integers that solve this?

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't recall any.  My elementary group theory nomenclature memory has not been refreshed in some time! Cheers!