# Application of Lagrange's Theorem to $Z/2018Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the order of the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2018\mathbb{Z}$ generated by 8.

I know that since the order of $\mathbb{Z}/2018\mathbb{Z}$ is finite I can use Lagrange's theorem which says that the order of the sungroup generated by 8 must divide the order of $\mathbb{Z}/2018\mathbb{Z}$ which is 2018.

Now I am not sure where to go from here besides brute force checking which divisor of 2018 is the order of the subgroup generated by 8

Is there some other theorem or fact I could use to make my life easier?

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906718/how-to-prove-ak-n-gcdn-k-whenever-a-n) might help.

Comment: Can you factorize $2018$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\,\ 2018\mid 8n\iff 1009\mid 4n\iff 1009\mid n$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* In a cyclic group of order $n$ generated by $g$, the subgroup generated by $g^k$ has order $n/\gcd(n,k)$.