# Intuition behind Order of an element of finite cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Let $\color{brown}{C}$ be a finite cyclic group, and $\color{brown}{a\in C}$ , such that $\color{brown}{|a|=n}$, then $$\color{green}{|a^k|=\frac{n}{gcd(k,n)}=\frac{lcm(k,n)}{k}}$$How to intuitively think/justify the above mathematical statement.
$$\color{grey}{any\quad help\quad is \quad deeply\quad appreciated}$$

Comment: Just play around with the case $n=6$, say, to get a feeling?

Comment: Can you intuitively understand it in the special case of a permutation? If so, then the theorem follows from Cayley's theorem (every group is a group of permutations)

Comment: Looking for something where we talk about role of gcd/LCM in deciding the least positive power for a^k

Comment: I think, a decent proof helps a lot for "intuitively think/justify". See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906718/how-to-prove-ak-n-gcdn-k-whenever-a-n). Then of course some examples with small $n$ are helpful.

Comment: The closest thing I could come with is you should convince yourself that $\mid a^k \mid = n$ for $n,k$ relatively prime. And because of the minimality of the order, for the general case it is necessary to divide $n$ by the gcd. The second and third equality is pretty trivial.

Comment: If $\mid a^k \mid = h < n$ then you could take $hk$ by the modulo $n$ and end up with an order for $a$ that is less than $n,$ that is a contradiction. You could also verify that $a^{k^n} = e.$

Comment: All the comments are helpful. The last comment which states result $a^{k^n}=e$ looks dubious as that $\Rightarrow n|{k^n} $ which is not always possible. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The possibility holds true $\iff  lcm(k^n,n}=k^n$