# how to find p-th primitive root of unity in GF(2^m)

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory, roots-of-unity, quadratic-residues

The definition of [quadratic residue codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue_code)  involves finding a primitive p-th root of unity in some finite extension field of $GF(2)$. 2 is a quadratic residue of prime $p$.
By brute force search I found solutions for $p=7, \zeta=Z(2^3)$ and $p=23,\zeta=Z(2^{11})^{89}$; $Z(2^m)$ is a primitive element in $GF(2^m)$. My question is how is this solved in general? In particular, what is the solution for $p=47$?

Comment: In every group, if an element $a$ has order $n$, then $a^k$ has order $n/\gcd(n,k)$. If $\zeta$ is a primitive element of the field $GF(2^{23})$ it has order $2^{23}-1$. As 
$$\frac{2^{23}-1}{47}=178481,$$
we can conclude that $\zeta^{178481}$ is a root of unity of order $47$.

Comment: See for example [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906718/11619) and others linked to it.

Comment: Compare: The exponent $89$ is similarly gotten as $(2^{11}-1)/23$.

Comment: thanks...this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered to some satisfaction in the comment by [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen), as written by the poster in another comment.

From the comments:

1. "In every group, if an element $a$ has order $n$, then $a^k$ has order $n / \text{gcd}(n,k)$. If $\zeta$ is a primitive element of the field $GF(2^{23})$ it has order $2^{23}-1$. As $$\frac{2^{23}-1}{47} = 178481,$$ we conclude that $\zeta^{178481}$ is a root of unity of oder 47."
2. "See for example [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906718/how-to-prove-rm-orderak-n-gcdn-k-for-n-rm-ordera) and others linked to it."
3. "Compare: The exponent $89$ is similarly gotten as $(2^{11}-1)/23$."